# Disable buttons after clicking a button

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, button, ibaction

I am working on a quiz app and I need to find a way to disable specific buttons in my UIView controller when I press on the correct answer i.e a button. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Relevant code:

```
myButton.enabled = NO;
```

but I do not have IBOutlets, I have IBActions.

Comment: Why aren't you able to create outlets?

Comment: should I just create outlets and set them to my buttons and use that code?

Answer (score 2):

simply create an IBOutlet in the class where your IBAction is, and bind the IBOutlet to you button. then you can use your referring code.